# Is there anything else other than class, interface or Enum?

Tags: java

As we know to generate a class file there should be atleast one class or interface or an Enum should be declared in the java file.

So i was curious that is there anything else as well other the mentioned which can cause a class file generation.

Or did anybody think that as we can declare the above mentioned, we can declare this(Which you think) as well ?

Comment: Maybe see AspectJ and aspects? it is extension of Java Language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are annotations.

```
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
    String someValue();
}
```

And then there are other languages like Scala that compile things to class files.

Comment: it is nothing but interface rite?

Comment: Annotations are different from interfaces (even though they are declared as @interface).

Comment: @GK: it's already in the answer: it's an annotation: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any other way apart from enum, interface and class. I dont consider annotation as different ones

Comment: If you don't consider annotations different from interfaces, then you probably shouldn't consider enums different from classes, either.